# AFNetworking memory allocation keeps rising

Tags: ipad, memory-management, uiimageview, afnetworking

I'm making an app which will fetch pictures resources and text from web service. I pick the great AFNetworking's UIImageView+AFNetworking category to deal with the image downloading stuff.

However, I'm facing a memory problem. I used **Allocation** tool of the **Instruments**, finding each time I load more images, there will always be a growth of memory allocation, 1-2 MB in size. I tracked down to the source code, it turned out that it lies in AFNetworking's code.

The exact line of code is:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)__unused connection {
    self.responseData = [self.outputStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];

    [self.outputStream close];

    [self finish];

    self.connection = nil;
}
```

This will occupy 99.6% of the memory allocation.

I user ARC in the project, display the UIImageViews in a UITableView and configure the cell like the following code:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURLRequest:request
                          placeholderImage:nil
                                   success:successBlock
                                   failure:failBlock];
```

Can any one offer some idea about the memory issue? It's really a headache cuz once the memory is allocated, they will never be cleared even if I cleared the whole image view. After a little while, my app will occupy more than 100MB from the **Real Memory Usage** window of **Instruments**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I've just opened an issue: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/509

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to clear the cache of images. There is a discussion about it on github here:

[AFNetworking Image Cache](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/109)

That may or may not solve your problem. I would imagine clearing the cache on a regular basis should keep your memory usage down though.